# How to deploy ipa archives to artifactory?

Tags: ios, repository, artifactory, ipa

Hhaving a CI like jenkins, how to deploy the IPA archives to the jfrog artifactory. Do I need cocoapods or other plugin? Can it be done using standard basic artifactory? What other tools could be used as a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple shell command in Jenkins to execute Artifactory [REST](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) api or better yet use Artifactory's [CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles) to upload any type of file to your Artifactory Server.

HTH,
Or